# Carousel loading failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to call bootstrap carousel slider from a separate html file but it doesn't work. Only the first image appears and other images don't slide. The carousel slider is in a file called `home.html`:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/insole_01.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/insole_02.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/insole_03.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/insole_04.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm calling it in my `index.html` file with a div tag:

```
<div class="products"></div>
```

And this is the Javascript code for the carousel:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 3500
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.products').load('products/home.html');
  $('.dropdown-menu>li').find('a').on('click', function(e){
    var links = $(this).attr('href');
    $('div.products').load(links).hide().fadeIn('300');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Any help please!

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: Can you show us where you import jquery and what carousel you are using?

Comment: The code for the carousel is above it's a simple bootsrap carousel.

Comment: I already solved the problem. It was in the Callback function.

Comment: Thank you however!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the jQuery `load()` you should use the `Callback Function`, run your code only after the html loaded.

(also make sure your path are correct)

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("div.products").load("products/home.html", function() {

    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 500
    });

    $('div.products').load('products/home.html');
    $('.dropdown-menu>li').find('a').on('click', function(e) {
      var links = $(this).attr('href');
      $('div.products').load(links).hide().fadeIn('300');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("div.products").load("products/home.html", function() {

    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 500
    });

    $('div.products').load('products/home.html');
    $('.dropdown-menu>li').find('a').on('click', function(e) {
      var links = $(this).attr('href');
      $('div.products').load(links).hide().fadeIn('300');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/insole_01.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/insole_02.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/insole_03.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/insole_04.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="products">

</div>
```

Comment: @Alex_984g Cool, Welcome to stackOverflow, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!